# I wonder what I (will or would) be doing in three years time?

Tags: modal-verbs, verb-forms, future-tense

What is the correct verb tense?

> I wonder what I will be doing in three years time?

or

> I wonder what I would be doing in three years time?

Comment: Hi, you can try [Spanish Stack Exchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) for your previous question. The tag translation here is not intended for a translation request. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question of tense as such, but of choosing between different "modal verbs" which express different levels of possibility or likelihood.

"Would" would be appropriate if you were expressing something that *could have happened* in the future *but only if* something else was true *that actually isn't*. (This is called the "irrealis mood", technically.) Here's an example:

> I wonder what I **would** be doing in three years' time **if I hadn't spotted that Help Wanted sign in the window**?

"Will" is what you want here, since you're expressing something that's bound to happen. You will be doing *something* in three years, no matter what, even if it's only "slowly rotting in a grave" or something similarly morbid.

Answer (score -1):

In this context which is in the future 'will' is the more appropriate. You wonder what you will be in the future, and in such later circumstances 'will' is preferably used. 'Would' is not entirely wrong in this context but is reserved more for past experiences, for example: Would I have gone to the theatre I would have missed seeing you.

Answer (score -1):

In the current context, "will" is the appropriate keyword. The keyword "would" would have been appropriate if the sentence was a type of indirect speech:

> I wondered what I would be doing in 3 years time.

Comment: That's different in tense, but it's possible to report speech indirectly in present tense: "I **wonder what I will be doing** in three years' time, then decide, as I take another bite of cereal, that there's simply no way to know for sure."

Comment: Yes, but that's about the tense of the indirect speech. Wonder - present simple, so the verb would be in it's original form. Wondered - past simple - one tense back - the verb would be one tense back - past future. Isn't it like that?

Comment: My point is that your explanation doesn't really help distinguish the two possibilities *for the actual tense being used*. It goes off on a bunny trail about changing something else that's not related.